# Reconnect to server in 5 seconds c# (Task)

Tags: c#, task, wait

So i have this SimpleClient.cs class that handles a async (begin/end) connection to a server. This client can be disconnected, and i need to try & reconnect after 5 seconds.

I get the disconnected event from the SimpleClient and i want to wait 5 seconds before i try & BeginConnect again.

Whats the best approach ?
Im thinking about using a Task and a .Wait for the 5 seconds then try the reconnect. I need other opinions about it if there is a better way of achieving this.
Thanks !

Comment: Oh yeah.. how do i close this one please?

Comment: Leave teh admins will mark it as duplicated.